# Visual Studio 2017 installer extremely slow

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I tried to install the latest VS 2017 Update yesterday and since then I cannot get it to finish this.

This worked pretty fine in the last months and stopped working yesterday.

I already tried to do the following:

- Uninstall VS 2017
- Remove folder `%PROGRAMFILESx86%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017`
- Remove folder `%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Visual Studio`
- Restart machine

I have a 50 MBit/s download rate and all other apps are working just fine. If I look into the logs I can see failed downloads when I abort the instalation. When I pick one of the URLs there and just download the vsix directly via the browser it just works.

Is there any caching or network setting that might be useful in this case?

**UPDATE**
I have tried 2 downloads (WLAN) from MS servers right now:

[image: Poor download rate from visualstudio.com]

[image: Good download rate from MS Download]

Has MS issues on certain download servers maybe and what to do or whom to tell in those cases?

Comment: I think you need to give us some more information. Is it stuck or just slow? In what phase?

Comment: @bennofs I think it is just very very slow. When I overwatch the Packages-folder mentioned above I can see them coming in. When I watch the procresses in resource monitor it says an avg download rate of 700 KBit/s

Comment: From Germany I'm getting the same slow download speed from that server.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem with VS2017 Preview. I disabled IPV6 in the network adapter properties. After that the installer ran with full download speed.

Comment: I was getting ~50Kbps, I then enabled IPV6 and got ~40Mbps. So enabling it worked for me. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Thank you - this solved my issues. I've been battling this on my new laptop for a while.

Answer (score 5):

After some heavy investigation and because of the feedback of  [trinitrotoluol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2379370/trinitrotoluol) I solved the issue by using an external VPN endpoint. That means, that my German hoster (Telekom) has got problems with some Microsoft download-servers. We contacted them but (not very suprisingly) there is no way to encourage them to examine their network a little bit deeper. So turns out that we have to wait until they fix this back or use a VPN client for such cases.

Comment: Yes, that's the best way to use vpn. My download speed increased from 50kb/sec to 500
Thanks for this info

Answer (score 2):

change download location via hosts (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) entries:
I checked alternative servers with [ping-test.ru](https://ping-test.ru)

For example:
93.184.215.201     download.visualstudio.microsoft.com
or
68.232.34.200     download.visualstudio.microsoft.com
or
192.229.232.200     download.visualstudio.microsoft.com
or
27.22.54.160     download.visualstudio.microsoft.com